# How to resolve duplicate SQL query mapping

Tags: nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

This is my first project with NHibernate, and I have an issue with the mappings. My domain class mappings are done using FluentNhibernate fluent mappings, which are working fine.

But now I need to map a stored procedure, which means I need to rely on `hbm.xml` files. So I added one called `NamedQueries.hbm.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" >
  <sql-query name="GetLatestTrackings">
    <return-scalar column="TrackingId" type="Int32" />
    <![CDATA[
      exec Core.GetLatestTrackings
    ]]>
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The fluent mapping looks like this:

```
        FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration
                          .MsSql2008
                          .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("Con")))
            .Mappings(m =>
                {
                    m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(assemblyWithMappings);
                    m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(assemblyWithMappings);
                });

        var nhibConfig = configuration.BuildConfiguration();

        SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(nhibConfig);

        return configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
```

But at runtime I'm getting the following exception:

> *DuplicateMappingException, Duplicate query / sql-query mapping
>   GetLatestTrackings*

At the moment I'm considering turning to ADO.NET for stored procedure calls, since I'm all out of ideas to map them through NHibernate.

Comment: where do you use this named query? Maybe you can integrate it in a fluentmapping using a formula